# Enlarge & move images on hover with CSS (no JavaScript) IE 9 and above

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, resize, hover

As the title states, I would like to both enlarge and move several images to a fixed location with CSS.  Each image will enlarge to the same width and move to the same location.  I know this is possible with javascript and with the CSS3 transition property. I want to know if it can be done with only CSS, and still be viewable in IE >= 9. This is the code I have:

```
<div class="logos"><a href=""><img src="" alt="" title="" /></a></div>



.logos {height: 100px; width: 100px;} 
.logos a img{max-height: 100%;
}

.logos a img:hover{
    position: fixed;
    max-width: 440px;
    top: 250px; left: 10%;
}
```

The problem: There is a grey background behind the original image and the enlarged/moved image.  Also, the enlarged/moved image flashes. The problem occurs when tested with .png and .jpg images. Is there a better way to do this with CSS or do I need to use javascript?

I want to stick with CSS because I prefer to use something I am familiar with, instead of copying and pasting a random piece of code. That way, when I have a new need or problem, I can figure it... out or at least understand the solution when it's given to me. :)  Thanks in adavance for your help!

Comment: More comphrehesively: What versions of IE do you need to support and what types of images are being used (.gif, .png, jpg)?

Comment: IE9 & 10.  The images are .png and .jpg

Answer (score 3):

It flashes because when the image has moved it is no longer there and thus is not hovered anymore, you could do it like this:

```
 .logos a,.logos a img
 {
     max-height: 100%;
     display: block;
     width:100px;
     height:200px;
 }

 .logos a:hover img
 {
     border: solid 12px black;
     position: fixed;
     right: 10px; 
     top: 10px; 
     z-index:10;
 }
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you could accept it as the correct answer.